# How to create unit test using ruby for Kubernetes cluster resources

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster and want to write test cases in ruby for different resources of the cluster. These test cases should include pod count, service available, ingress is present etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A few options out there:

- [kubeclient](https://github.com/abonas/kubeclient)
- [Kubernetes Ruby client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/ruby)
- [k8s client](https://github.com/kontena/k8s-client)
- Write your own.

Connect to the kube-apiserver using any of these libraries and request pod count, ingress present, etc.